# injecting a spring bean property different values according to its context

Tags: spring, spring-el

I have a spring bean `my_bean` with a property `my_map`, and I want to inject it with the value "X" or with the value "Y". The bean:

```
<bean id="my_bean">
  <property name="my_map">
    <map>
      <entry key="p" value="X" />
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

It's referenced in a very deep hierarchy by the bean `root_a`:

```
<bean id="root_a">
  <ref bean="root_a_a"/>
</bean>
<bean id="root_a_a">
  <ref bean="root_a_a_a"/>
</bean>
<bean id="root_a_a_a">
  <ref bean="my_bean"/>
</bean>
```

and this entire deep hierarchy is referenced again from the bean `root_b`. In the ref of my_bean from this hierarchy I would the property to be injected with the value "Y", but I would not like to duplicate the entire hierarchy twice.

```
<bean id="root_b">
  <ref bean="root_a_a"/>
</bean>
```

How do I do this in the spring XML? can you think of a clever spring EL solution? something else? I prefer all my configuration to be done in the XML and no Java code...

Comment: might be vital information: In a single execution of my application, I never use both root_a and root_b. In each execution, I select and use only one of them.

Comment: maybe you want to try profile/environment introduced in 3.1 ? [Spring Team Blog Entry](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/)

Comment: spring profiles sound exactly like what I need. Do you have a workaround using spring 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Spring beans are singletons, which means that once `bean="my_bean"` is created it is shared between other components e.g. shared between A => `bean id="root_a_a_a"` and B => `bean id="root_b_b_b"`

The answer to your question depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

### Two Beans

If `bean="my_bean"` does not need to be shared between A and B, then create two beans:

inject this one to A

```
<bean id="myBeanX" class="My">
  <property name="culprit" value="X"/>
</bean>
```

and this one to B

```
<bean id="myBeanY" class="My">
  <property name="culprit" value="Y"/>
</bean>
```

notice they both are instances of the same class.

You can also inline them into collaborators (A / B) if you don't need them for anything else:

```
<bean id="root_a_a_a">
  <constructor-arg>
    <bean class="My">
      <property name="culprit" value="X"/>
    </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

You can also have a factory bean that creates `root_a_a_a` given the property for a class `My`, but that would be an overkill.

### Single Bean

In case A and B needs to share the exact same reference to `bean="my_bean"`, the question is: are you ok with A and B changing `my_bean`'s state after `my_bean` is created? Probably **not**.

If you *are*, which would be 0.41172% chance, you can change `my_bean`'s value to whatever you need in A's or B's constructors => would **not** recommend

Hence you either would go with the `Two Bean` approach (which is most likely what you want), or you would need to refactor a property for "X" and "Y" into another e.g. `myConfig` component.

---

#### *EDIT after the question was edited*

If `root_a` and `root_b` will **not** be used together in the same instance of the context,you can use Spring Profiles ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435246/spring-injecting-different-properties-file-according-to-profile/9440209#9440209)), or SpEL / Property Based solutions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470551/spring-property-substitution-for-test-and-production/9471696#9471696))

e.g.

```
<bean id="my_bean">
  <property name="my_map">
    <map>
      <entry key="p" value="${ENV_SYSTEM:X}" />
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

It will set it to `X` by default, unless a ENV_SYSTEM system variable is set (e.g. to `Y`).

Comment: thanks a lot! your detailed answer showed me that I had a mistake in my question, as I can't use the "two beans" strategy as I have an entire hierarchy I would like to reuse without duplicating. rephrased. Still looking for something more elegant than the "single bean" solution you suggested

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it's cool. However I used a slightly different solution. I created 2 new XML files: root_a.xml and root_b.xml and put the 2 different roots there + each has a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer which `my_property=X` or `my_property=Y` and in `my_bean` I've put `value="${my_property}"`